# get error while posting tweet from twitter client using twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter

i get a error message when i try to update my status from my twitter client.
it works fine when iam reading statuses with the getHomeTimeLine() Method.
i really dont know where the error could be.
please help!

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
        AccessToken accessToken = null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (null == accessToken) {
          System.out.println("Open the following URL and grant access to your account:");
          System.out.println(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
          System.out.print("Enter the PIN(if aviailable) or just hit enter.[PIN]:");
          String pin = br.readLine();
          try{
             if(pin.length() > 0){
               accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, pin);
             }else{
               accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
             }
          } catch (TwitterException te) {
            if(401 == te.getStatusCode()){
              System.out.println("Unable to get the access token.");
            }else{
              te.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
          System.out.println("token = "+accessToken.getToken());
          System.out.println("tokenSecret = "+accessToken.getTokenSecret());
        }
```

this is my method for the login

```
public void login()throws TwitterException{
    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory();
    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(token, tokenSecret);
    Configuration conf = new PropertyConfiguration(new Properties());
    OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization(conf);
    auth.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    auth.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
    twitterClient = factory.getInstance(auth);
}
```

this is my method for the status update

```
public void setStatus(String text) throws TwitterException {

    if(twitterClient==null)throw new IllegalStateException("Please login first : ");
    Status status; 
    try {
        status = twitterClient.updateStatus(text);
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    System.out.println("Status : "+status.getText());
}
```

these are my error messages:

> 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid conumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.
>   error - Read-only application cannot POST
>   request - /1/statuses/update.json
>   Relevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
>       http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b2b52c28 or
>       http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=1b433fc8
>   TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-1b433fc8], statusCode=401, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.6-SNAPSHOT(build: 404bccc2082954dc0d12612322791a37f3daa917)}
>       at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:185)
>       at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
>       at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:102)
>       at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.post(TwitterImpl.java:1927)
>       at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.updateStatus(TwitterImpl.java:433)
>       at twitter.Zwietschi.setStatus(Zwietschi.java:74)
>       at twitter.Zwietschi.main(Zwietschi.java:93)

where is the problem?
please help!

Answer (score 3):

Check if you've changed permissions... You'll have to regenerate tokens then!!!

Comment: Looks like this exception code is used for multiple purposes. I am for example getting it with a status of -1 for broken pipe when uploads take too long.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me, you should try with the ConfigurationBuilder.

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("YOUR_APP_KEY");
cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("YOUR_APP_SECRET");
cb.setOAuthAccessToken("USER_TOKEN_KEY");
cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("USER_TOKEN_SECRET");

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();   
String tweet="HELLO WORLD!";
twitter.updateStatus(tweet);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like as of today (jan 14) this error is also thrown, when not using an ssl connection.

See [REST API, regarding 403 error code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130292/rest-api-regarding-403-error-code/21134302#21134302) for solution (enable SSL, use latest twitter4j).

Answer (score 1):

This implementation worked for me in version Twitter4J API 3.0.3.

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey(Config.CONSUMER_KEY)
.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Config.CONSUMER_SECRET)
.setOAuthAccessToken(Config.ACCESS_TOKEN)
.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(Config.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
cb.setUseSSL(true);                 
TwitterFactory twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();
```

The line that makes it works is

```
cb.setUseSSL(true);
```

Heard that is the default on Twitter4J API 3.0.5.