# REST API, regarding 403 error code?

Tags: java, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

We are posting Tweets to multiple accounts from same IP address using software application. And in response from twitter , we are getting 403 error code, API used by us is REST API.

Is there any limitations on IP address, because surely we are not crossing API post limit mentioned for REST API.

We are also not going above 140 characters.

Waiting for reply..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Twitter always gives you an error message along with a 403. What does the error message say?

Comment: 403 Forbidden The request is understood, but it has been refused or access is not allowed. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits.

Comment: @AmitBadgujar - This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits.

Comment: @AmitBadgujar You're just posting the description from https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses. The actual 403 will have an error message attached.

Comment: I have printed that same error code in my application, that's why i have posted same description.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is a recent error (since Jan 14th) you can try to add this:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setUseSSL(true); // <======== set use SSL
```

`Twitter` added a requirement on January 14th to use `SSL/HTTPS` when using their API.

The above code fixed it for me.

Comment: Its not working now. May be due to new changes in twitter api

Answer (score 3):

api.twitter.com now requires SSL/TLS for all connections as of today(14th jan2014)

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

cb.setUseSSL(true);
```

Put these above lines of code where you are making a call to twitter.

It works...

Answer (score 2):

if you are using twitter4j.properties, you can also set it there.
http.useSSL=true

Answer (score 0):

If this is the exception that is being thrown and if you read the error it says:

This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits.