# TwitterException: Unable to login

Tags: android, twitter4j

I have "login With Twitter" button in my application.

yesterday I log-in with twitter it perfectly works.

But today it doesn't. I am attaching my log with same question .

```
01-15 14:47:44.812: W/System.err(11435): 403:The request is understood, but it has been 
                    refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code 
                    is used when requests are being denied due to update limits 
                    (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-
                    update-api-dm-and-following).

01-15 14:47:44.812: W/System.err(11435): Relevant discussions can be found on the 
                    Internet at:
01-15 14:47:44.812: W/System.err(11435): http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=10f5ada3 or
01-15 14:47:44.812: W/System.err(11435): http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=e574402b
01-15 14:47:44.812: W/System.err(11435): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[10f5ada3- 
                    e574402b], statusCode=403, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, 
                    rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}ent.java:828)
011514:47:44.812:W/System.err(11435):
               twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:177)

01-15 14:47:44.812: W/System.err(11435):    at   
             twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
01-15 14:47:44.812: W/System.err(11435): 
  attwitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:122) 



01-15 14:47:44.812: W/System.err(11435): at  
    twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:104)
```

01-15 14:47:44.812: W/System.err(11435):     at
                 twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:281)

Comment: of course your read the error and the attached links?

Comment: yes I read it , I have not cross the limits.

Comment: that's an important information to avoid answers such as `you have exceeded your limits`. Could you elaborate on the verification process to assert that you have not exceeded said limits ?

Comment: from 15-16 hours before I am not posted anything ,even not login with twitter as I clicked on login button it show me this error.

Comment: can I use other consumer and consumer secret key? so this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: fixed the issue,  upgrading(3.0.3) to the latest version of twitter4j 3.0.5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Upgrade** your `twitter4j library` to `twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar`. I was facing the same problem and solved it by upgrading the library.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out Twitter from January 14th, 2014 forces API calls to made through SSL, if you use standard HTTP you will get the error you are seeing. This matches the timeframe you mention.

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239

https://twitter.com/twitterapi/status/422807297048326144

Comment: ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

**cb.setUseSSL(true);**

The above code thats in bold, enables SSL for twitter4j.

Answer (score 2):

This error seems to be also thrown, when not using SSL for login (as of 14 jan).

See [REST API, regarding 403 error code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130292/rest-api-regarding-403-error-code/21134302#21134302) for possible solution.