# Twitter REST API Not able to login

Tags: java, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am using Twitter4j to login to twitter but its not working. I tried [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130292/rest-api-regarding-403-error-code/21134302) but it is not working now.

```
ConfigurationBuilder twitterConf = new ConfigurationBuilder();
twitterConf.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKeyValue)
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecretValue) 
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(twitterConf.build()).getInstance();
// twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKeyValue,consumerSecretValue)
RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
println requestToken 
println "Updated: " + requestToken.getTokenSecret()   
redirect(url:requestToken.getAuthorizationURL())
```

I am getting this error:

> Executing action [authorizeapp] of controller
>   [com.igh.social.auth.TwitterConnectController] caused exception:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target Relevant discussions
>   can be found on the Internet at:
>   http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=8872ef79 or
>   http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=8764957d
>   TwitterException{exceptionCode=[8872ef79-8764957d 8872ef79-87649553
>   8872ef79-87649553 8872ef79-87649553], statusCode=-1, message=null,
>   code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.5}

Please help me on this. I just want to sign up to my app using twitter.

Comment: You are missing some `;` and other stuff in your code. In which line does the eception occur? Do you have a complete stacktrace?

Comment: Thnaks for helping , I am using this code in grails so there is no need of semicolon(;) here is Stacktrace

`sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)`